Charge position in 7-norbornyl cation?
So I stumbled over this representation of the 7-norbornyl cation:

(Römpp, 10. Ed., p. 189, Anchimere Hilfe)
And two questions came to my mind that I haven't been able to solve so far: (1) Why is the hydrogen explicitly shown on C7? (2) Why is the positive charge not on C7? Apparently, C7 must have a formal positive charge since its empty orbital interacts with the double bond.


Most likely, the single hydrogen is shown on C-7 to indicate that it is just one hydrogen atom attached there. If this position were left blank, the normal carbon valence would (incorrectly) imply two hydrogen atoms.

It looks like the book misplaced the positive charge. C-7 should be positively charged and electron-deficient in the first contributing structure; the bridgehead carbons with four attached atoms are not.



Thank you for the confirmation! The explicit hydrogen would, of course, be unnecessary if the single positive charge were already located at C-7, as only one hydrogen could then be attached(?)

Placing the positive charge vorrectly would work.
